# Keeping the keyboard from obscuring widgets in a form

Tags: iphone

In an iPhone app, how do I keep the software keyboard from obscuring buttons, or UITextView fields in a View?

I've got the following layout:

```
View -\
     UITextView
     UIButton
```

... but, the keyboard obscures the button at the bottom when I'm typing in the UITextView. I tried using the following:

```
View -\
     UIScrollView -\
         UITextView
         UIButton
```

... but, the window does not scroll as expected, so the user has no way of clicking the button.

How is this normally handled?

Note:  I do not want to scroll down automatically to make the button visible.  I just want the user to be able to scroll down when they are done typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You manually set the coordinates of the controls when the keyboard appears and disappears. Or you use a UIScrollView and manually set the scroll offset.

Comment: I don't want to automatically scroll it.  I want the user to be able to scroll the view to see the button when they are done typing.  Like the "Compose Mail" dialog in the Mail app.

Answer (score 0):

You should tell the UIScrollView scrollTo... and you must figure out how far to scroll based on what input field was selected that caused the keyboard to appear.

Comment: Again, I don't want it to scroll automatically.  I want the user to be able to scroll down to see the button whenever they want.